# I've been here before I became me

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Who am I?

> I've been here before I became me
>
> I'm wise and bold, you're about to see
>
> Carly Simon, it's not my sin
>
> I'm the one who'll have the green
>
> All of you, who are reading this
>
> Will know my name if you persist
>
> (If this all seems vague, don't scorn
>
> I'll explain it when I'm born)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd wager that you are:

> the **answerer** *(me, in this case)*

I've been here before I became me

> The answerer visited and viewed this question before answering and becoming the answerer.

I'm wise and bold, you're about to see

> While there can be numerous respondents, only one is wise (or bold/quick enough) to be the true answerer with the true answer.

Carly Simon, it's not my sin

> Carly Simon sang "***You're So Vain***- you probably think this song is about you..." Well, this puzzle is about me, since I am answering it, becoming the answerer.

I'm the one who'll have the green

> Since I am the answerer, I will be the one to receive the green tick.

All of you, who are reading this

Will know my name if you persist

> If you continue to read down the page to this answer here, you will know both the answer and the answerer, and that they are in a way, one in the same.

(If this all seems vague, don't scorn

I'll explain it when I'm born)

> Since I reckon that I have the answer, and since I've now answered with it, I can tell you that the answer is the answerer. Straightforward, no?

Comment: I expected the first block to say "me!", I guess you managed to not be as vain :)

Comment: @Dotan Yeah, I was going to emphasize ME a bit more, especially at the end, but what can I say, enough repeated listenings of Carly Simon must have pummeled a shred of humility into me.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a meta one: are you

> the correct/accepted answer on Stack Exchange?

*I've been here before I became me*

> The answer was here before becoming an accepted answer.

*I'm wise and bold, you're about to see*

> Not sure about this.

*Carly Simon, it's not my sin*

> I looked up Carly Simon and apparently she's a singer. Googling "Carly Simon sin" led me to [this song](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/carlysimon/puresin.html) - relevant?

*I'm the one who'll have the green*

> The green tickmark. (**This line was the giveaway, if this answer is correct.**)

*All of you, who are reading this*
*Will know my name if you persist*

> If you read the riddle, and then scroll down and read the accepted answer, you'll know the solution.

*(If this all seems vague, don't scorn*
*I'll explain it when I'm born)*

> The accepted answer, when it comes, should explain the solution.

Comment: Just beat you to it :) (I guess your answer is a bit different though)